# Copy Elements From One Page To Another in Multipage with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, multipage

I have a multipage in a userform. During run-time, the user can choose to add x number of pages at any time. The elements of each page will be the same. I am wondering if there is a way to duplicate these elements, or would I need to re-create these same elements for each new page? If so, how do I specify locations on the page where the element should be placed?

[image]

Comment: You can duplicate them by copying and pasting or by creating from scratch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick is to put all controls in a frame in the 1st page and then the rest becomes easy :)

This code will copy the controls from `Page1` to `Page2` after creating `Page2` and align them accordingly.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim l As Double, r As Double
    Dim ctl As Control

    MultiPage1.Pages.Add

    MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls.Copy
    MultiPage1.Pages(1).Paste

     For Each ctl In MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.Frame Then
            l = ctl.Left
            r = ctl.Top
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    For Each ctl In MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls
        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.Frame Then
            ctl.Left = l
            ctl.Top = r
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

Comment: When I run the above code, I get a "Run-time error '-2147417949 (80010108)': Automation error the object invoked as diconnected from its clients."

Comment: which line is giving you the error? I just tested it again and it works.

Comment: if I comment everything out and leave just `MultiPage1.Pages.Add` it gives me the error

Comment: That's strange. Can you upload thefile that you created just now and upload it in say wikisend.com and then share the link here.

Comment: I think there's some underlying issue affecting all my userforms in that same project. I created a new project add userform and tried the above code and it works. I'll try re-creating the userform and see what happens

Comment: You don´t actually have to use a frame if you are just going to replicate the page inside the Multipage. Just use controls.copy and then .paste and that should do.

Answer (score 1):

The "Run-time error '-2147417949 (80010108)' may be caused by having a Frame somewhere else on the form. Try removing any other frames and running again.