# Adding Click Behaviour to Dynamically Created Form Control Button with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, button, command

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822450/copy-elements-from-one-page-to-another-in-multipage-with-vba-in-excel), where a userform allows the creation of x # of tabs in a multipage during runtime, each with the same controls, I am wondering how to set the .OnClick behaviour of the buttons. I am trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
For Each ctl In MultiPage1.Pages(NumSegs - 1).Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
        ctl.Name = "Segment" & NumSegs & "Button"
        ctl.OnClick = "Span_Form_Click_Handler"
    End If
Next
```

But of course there doesn't seem to be a .OnClick method...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592641/assign-event-handlers-to-controls-on-user-form-created-dynamically-in-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define a variable with events.
A minimal example: UserForm + CommandButton on it. Code in UserForm Module:

```
Public WithEvents btn As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub btn_Click()
    MsgBox "Bla"
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Set btn = CommandButton1
End Sub
```

After a click in the form, the button CommandButton gets the sub btn_Click assigned.

To be able to call everytime the same sub, you need to place the sub and the withevents variable into a class and create an instance of this class for each CommandButton you find.