# VBa - Userform show same combobox on two pages

Tags: vba, userform, multipage

So I have a multipage where I want the same button to show on both pages. I could place it outside but the border from the multipage is so ugly so I tried to place everything on the pages. Unfortunately you can't name the items (such as the combobox) with the same name. Is there a workaround to remove the borders and just show the page names or have the same name on the item on two pages?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not that good in userforms but couldn't you use a name with suffix, and the suffix represents the page nr.? Meaning like DoItButton1 and DoItButton5 bc on page 1 and 5 is the same button and you reference it like "DoItButton"+pagenr?

Comment: So your multipage only has 2 pages? Depends on your need, sometimes a TabStrip is better especially when you have "Shared" controls.

Comment: Added two pictures to display a little more. @Kajkrow I'm currently trying to do that but it quickly becomes complicated as it is used quite much.

Comment: @PatricK Tried using that but didnt seem to get it to work, Currently I'm working to copy paste the items on the right to another page.

Comment: To use the TabStrip with easier hide/show relevant Controls, put the controls for each page into different invisible frame (either by default or at UserForm Initialize with **No Caption**, `SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat`). Then on `TabStrip1_Change` event, change the Visible state of the frames and place them to desired Top and Left.

Comment: @PatricK But is there any way when editing to prevent them from overlapping?

Comment: You can create a big UserForm with those frames at bottom and side by side, then at `UserForm_Initialize`, move them into desired Top, Left position, change Visible state according to the Active Tab, and change the Userform Width, Height to smaller.

Comment: You might find some use of [this answer from Siddharth Rout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10822863/9663006) which shows how to group relevant controls and move them when you change pages. I feel that the answer may not directly show you what you want but should give you the correct way of thinking to find a solution to your question. Otherwise, you might want to, as suggested above by @PatricK use a Tab Strip instead. You could set to the `TabStrip1_Change` event `If Me.Tabstrip1.value = 1 Then...Do some things...End If` which will "Do some things" if `Tab2` is selected (tabs are Zero-Indexed).

Answer (score 1):

Had some fun with this goal.

Consider this UserForm in Editor with TabStrip, 2 frames and some other controls.
Frames are named from `Frame0`, `Frame1`, etc.
Assuming the **Frame0** is the location reference and first to display when UserForm is displayed, code below will be what you want.

[image: UserForm Editor]

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TabStrip1_Change()
    Dim i As Long, lActiveTabIndex As Long
    lActiveTabIndex = Me.TabStrip1.Value
    For i = 0 To Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count - 1
        Me.Controls("Frame" & i).Visible = (i = lActiveTabIndex)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me
        .Height = 288 ' Adjust to your desired height
        ' Align all FrameX top/left to same as Frame0, delete Caption and SpecialEffect
        For i = 0 To Me.TabStrip1.Tabs.Count - 1
            With Me.Controls("Frame" & i)
                .Top = Me.Frame0.Top
                .Left = Me.Frame0.Left
                .Caption = ""
                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
            End With
        Next i
    End With
    ' Ensure frame for first tab is displayed
    TabStrip1_Change
End Sub
```

Userform first load (didn't save screenshot, neither the workbook, sorry).

Next tab clicked:
[image: next tab clicked]